# How can I compare elements in 2 lists in the same index in their respective lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, zip

Say I have 2 lists

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 1]
b = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1]
```

I want it to make a third list with only the elements that are equal in the same index in each list, in this case

```
c = [1, 2, 7, 1]
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: Just `zip` the lists and compare: `c = [x for x,y in zip(a,b) if x == y]`

Comment: @MarkMeyer This worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simplest method would probably just be doing a list comprehension:

```
c = [x for x,y in zip(a,b) if x == y]
```

for the sake of a different approach and just out of interest..could also do it this way:

```
from itertools import compress
mask = [x==y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
c = list(compress(a,mask))
```

or if numpy is an option (good for larger lists):

```
import numpy as np
a,b = np.array(a), np.array(b)
c = a[np.equal(a,b)].tolist()
```

all ways give:

```
[1, 2, 7, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the lists and return the test (which will return a variable of type `boolean`):

```
[i == j for i, j in zip(x_list, y_list)]
```

You could use `any` to quickly check for the existence of a `False` (it will be false when the two items are not the same) if you don't need the values:

```
any(i != j for i, j in zip(x_list, y_list))
```

The `any` version would break once a `False` is found meaning you may not have to traverse the whole lists except in the worst case.

Comment: The OP gave an example of the return value:  `[1, 2, 7, 1]` your code returns booleans.

Comment: The thing is I don't wanna see IF there are any that are equal, I wanna see their values

Answer (score 0):

If both lists are of equal length,`c = [val for ind, val in enumerate(a) if b[ind] == val]` should work.